# How to get user's photo url without transform?

Tags: users, craft3, image-transforms

**Craft 3**: I'm trying to get User Photo URL WITHOUT any transforms, but none of those options seems to work:
(some of it prints the url with some transform)

```
user.photo
user.getPhoto()
user.getPhoto('original')
user.getPhotoUrl()
user.getPhotoUrl('original')
user.photoUrl()
user.photoUrl('original')
```

There is no DOCs for this yet on the craft 3 site.
Anyone know?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Craft 3 source code](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/cf85fae8b84c7329e70ea96753ebb53d897f26fc/src/elements/User.php#L951-L970), `User::getPhotoUrl() has been deprecated. Use getPhoto() to access the photo asset (if there is one), and call its getUrl() method to access the photo URL.` *(Also mentioned in the [changelog](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/2e05ca4fa899e4e922562286767061b4ec9fe12b/CHANGELOG-v3.md#deprecated-12).)*

So assuming you've set `user` to something already in your template, the correct way to get the photo in Craft 3 is:

```
{{ user.photo.url() }}
```

Comment: To be absolutely clear about the no transformation (not even a default one): `{{ user.photo.url(null) }}` or `{{ user.photo.url(false) }}`